# Erroneous Queue Icon

Tags: bug

The "Review Queues" icon at the top right always shows a red dot when I visit Expatriates. The dropdown shows a red dot next to "Suggested Edits."

I like editing, so I usually respond and click on the entry to reveal the edit queue. But the edit queue is almost always empty, and the "Queue has been cleared" statement is displayed.

Is there a cache to empty, or something else for me to do, so that the erroneous notification is not displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have changed over the years, but I think this [MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302093/please-dont-red-alert-me-for-queues-ive-handled) reflects the current state: it is broken.